# Can you recommend an immutable and security audited escrow program that I can use?

Tags: program

I want to make something that requires an escrow, but it's probably better to make a CPI to something battle tested. Any recommendations?

Comment: The timelock program by streamflow might do the trick: https://github.com/StreamFlow-Finance/timelock-crate/

Answer (score 1):

i am not aware of a battle proofed audited frozen program, but this anchor program looks pretty good and is still maintained:

https://github.com/ironaddicteddog/anchor-escrow

And it's written with Anchor so it should be easy to build a client for it.